# nested component data inconsistency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I'm relatively new to react and I have a problem that I'm trying to debug for 2 days now
I'm creating some sort of popup component using 'reactjs-popup' and I'm passing to its props object called items it will always contain 3 information {fullName,Phone,Relation}.
Here's the Popup component class

```
export const PatientPopup = (props) => {
  const {
    width = '25%',
    height = '15vh',
    items = {},
    isOpenEmergencyContact = false, // Set a default value here
    setIsOpenEmergencyContact
  } = props;
  return (
    <Popup
      open={isOpenEmergencyContact}
      closeOnDocumentClick
      onClose={() => setIsOpenEmergencyContact(false)}
    >
      <Card><Scrollbar><Box
        sx={{ minWidth: 200 }}><Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
              Name
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              Mobile Number
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              Relationship
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          <TableRow key={items.fullName}>
            <TableCell>
              {items.fullName}
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              {items.mobileNumber}
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              {items.relation}
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>


        </TableBody>
      </Table></Box></Scrollbar></Card>
    </Popup>
  );
};

PatientPopup.propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.object,
  width: PropTypes.string,
  height: PropTypes.string
};
```

here is the Table component part that I call the popup component within
the thing is everything seems to be working fine however the data displayed on the popup is always the last indexed data in the array.
notice that this data is already coming from an array that I map on and then I pass the data to the popup component

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import IdentificationIcon from '@heroicons/react/24/solid/IdentificationIcon';
import Xmark from '@heroicons/react/24/solid/XMarkIcon';
import PencilIcon from '@heroicons/react/24/solid/PencilIcon';
import {
  Avatar,
  Box,
  Card,
  Checkbox, IconButton,
  Stack, SvgIcon,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TablePagination,
  TableRow,
  Typography
} from '@mui/material';
import { Scrollbar } from 'src/components/scrollbar';
import { getInitials } from 'src/utils/get-initials';
import { useState } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import Popup from 'reactjs-popup';
import 'reactjs-popup/dist/index.css';
import { indigo } from '../../../theme/colors';
import { PatientEmergencyPopup } from './PatientEmergency-Popup';
import { PatientDeletePopup } from './Patient-DeletePopup';

export const PatientTable = (props) => {
  const {
    count = 0,
    items = [],
    onPageChange = () => {},
    onRowsPerPageChange,
    page = 0,
    rowsPerPage = 0
  } = props;

  const [activeEmergencyContactId, setActiveEmergencyContactId] = useState(null);
  const [isOpenDelete, setOpenDelete] = useState(null);
  return (
    <Card>
      <Scrollbar>
        <Box sx={{ minWidth: 800 }}>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell align="center">
                  Name
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  Email
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  Gender
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  Phone
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  Username
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  Date of Birth
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  Password
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  Emergency Contact
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  Actions
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {items.map((customer) => {
                //const createdAt = format(customer.createdAt, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
                const relation = customer.emergencyContact.relation;
                const fullName = customer.emergencyContact.fullName;
                const mobileNumber = customer.emergencyContact.mobileNumber;
                console.log(customer.id);
                return (
                  <TableRow hover key={customer.id}>
                    <TableCell>
                      <Stack
                        alignItems="center"
                        direction="row"
                        spacing={2}
                      >
                        <Avatar src={customer.avatar}>
                          {getInitials(customer.name)}
                        </Avatar>
                        <Typography variant="subtitle2">
                          {customer.name}
                        </Typography>
                      </Stack>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      {customer.email}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      {customer.gender}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      {customer.mobileNumber}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      {customer.username}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      {customer.dob.substring(0, customer.dob.indexOf('T'))}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      {customer.password}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      <IconButton
                        color="primary"
                        onClick={() => {
                          setActiveEmergencyContactId(customer.id);
                        }}
                      >
                        <SvgIcon fontSize="large">
                          <IdentificationIcon/>
                        </SvgIcon>
                      </IconButton>
                      {customer.emergencyContact.fullName}
                      <PatientEmergencyPopup
                        items={
                          {
                            fullName: fullName,
                            mobileNumber: mobileNumber,
                            relation: relation
                          }
                        }
                        width={'25%'} height={'15vh'}
                        isOpenEmergencyContact={activeEmergencyContactId === customer.id}
                        onClose={() => setActiveEmergencyContactId(null)}/>

                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      <IconButton
                        color="primary"
                        onClick={() => {
                          setOpenDelete(true);
                        }}
                      >
                        <SvgIcon fontSize="small">
                          <Xmark/>
                        </SvgIcon>
                      </IconButton>
                      <IconButton
                        color="primary"
                        onClick={() => {
                          setOpenDelete(customer.id);
                        }}
                      >
                        <SvgIcon fontSize="small">
                          <PencilIcon/>
                        </SvgIcon>
                      </IconButton>
                      <PatientDeletePopup width={'25%'} height={'15vh'} isOpenDelete={isOpenDelete===customer.id}
                                          items={customer.name} onClose={() => setOpenDelete(null)}/>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                );
              })}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </Box>
      </Scrollbar>
      <TablePagination
        component="div"
        count={count}
        onPageChange={onPageChange}
        onRowsPerPageChange={onRowsPerPageChange}
        page={page}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
      />
    </Card>
  );
};

PatientTable.propTypes = {
  count: PropTypes.number,
  items: PropTypes.array,
  onPageChange: PropTypes.func,
  onRowsPerPageChange: PropTypes.func,
  page: PropTypes.number,
  rowsPerPage: PropTypes.number
};
```

Here's the Page class that has the table component

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { subDays, subHours } from 'date-fns';
import ArrowDownOnSquareIcon from '@heroicons/react/24/solid/ArrowDownOnSquareIcon';
import ArrowUpOnSquareIcon from '@heroicons/react/24/solid/ArrowUpOnSquareIcon';
import PlusIcon from '@heroicons/react/24/solid/PlusIcon';
import { Box, Button, Container, Stack, SvgIcon, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { useSelection } from 'src/hooks/use-selection';
import { Layout as DashboardLayout } from 'src/layouts/dashboard/admin/layout';
import { PatientTable } from 'src/sections/admin/Patients/Patient-Table';
import { PatientsSearch } from 'src/sections/admin/Patients/patients-search';
import { applyPagination } from 'src/utils/apply-pagination';
const useCustomers = (data, page, rowsPerPage) => {
  return useMemo(
    () => {
      return applyPagination(data, page, rowsPerPage);
    },
    [data, page, rowsPerPage]
  );
};

const useCustomerIds = (customers) => {
  return useMemo(
    () => {
      return customers.map((customer) => customer.id);
    },
    [customers]
  );
};

const Page = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);
  const customers = useCustomers(data, page, rowsPerPage);
  const customersIds = useCustomerIds(customers);
  const customersSelection = useSelection(customersIds);


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/iewPatients')
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.statusCode == 401) {
          throw new Error('Error while fetching data');
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data['patients']);
      })
      .catch((err) => {});
  }, []);

  const handlePageChange = useCallback(
    (event, value) => {
      setPage(value);
    },
    []
  );

  const handleRowsPerPageChange = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      setRowsPerPage(event.target.value);
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>
          Patients
        </title>
      </Head>
      <Box
        component="main"
        sx={{
          flexGrow: 1,
          py: 8
        }}
      >
        <Container maxWidth="xl">
          <Stack spacing={3}>
            <Stack
              direction="row"
              justifyContent="space-between"
              spacing={4}
            >
              <Stack spacing={1}>
                <Typography variant="h4">
                  Patients
                </Typography>
                <Stack
                  alignItems="center"
                  direction="row"
                  spacing={1}
                >
                  <Button
                    color="inherit"
                    startIcon={(
                      <SvgIcon fontSize="small">
                        <ArrowUpOnSquareIcon/>
                      </SvgIcon>
                    )}
                  >
                    Import
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    color="inherit"
                    startIcon={(
                      <SvgIcon fontSize="small">
                        <ArrowDownOnSquareIcon/>
                      </SvgIcon>
                    )}
                  >
                    Remove
                  </Button>
                </Stack>
              </Stack>
              <div>
                <Button
                  startIcon={(
                    <SvgIcon fontSize="small">
                      <PlusIcon/>
                    </SvgIcon>
                  )}
                  variant="contained"
                >
                  Add
                </Button>
              </div>
            </Stack>
            <PatientsSearch/>
            <PatientTable
              count={data.length}
              items={customers}
              onPageChange={handlePageChange}
              onRowsPerPageChange={handleRowsPerPageChange}
              page={page}
              rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
            />
          </Stack>
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

Page.getLayout = (page) => (
  <DashboardLayout>
    {page}
  </DashboardLayout>
);

export default Page;
```

is there any way to keep the data consistent among every row?

Comment: Can you also post where `fullName`, `mobileNumber` and `relation` are coming from, including all the state management around that. Easier to post the whole component for the second part.

Comment: Edited. Added the whole Table Class + Page class that I call the table within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be because you have one popup instance per entry in `items`, but you also have a state item `isOpenEmergencyContact` to control visibility that can only represent "on" and "off" and not a particular customer. That means that when you click on the button that calls `setIsOpenEmergencyContact(true)`, *all* of the popups open all at once on top of each other. Since they are overlapping, you see the last one, which is the one for the last item in the array.

To fix this we need to change `isOpenEmergencyContact` to be an identifier of *which* popup should be open and not just a plain bool. Probably we should change the name of it at the same time so it's more clear what that is. We will use `null` for when no popup is opened and the unique customer id for when it is open.

**PatientTable**

Change

```
const [isOpenEmergencyContact, setIsOpenEmergencyContact] = useState(false);
```

To

```
const [activeEmergencyContactId, setActiveEmergencyContactId] = useState(null);
```

This is just to rename the state item to make it more clear but also to use `null` as the new way of saying "no popup is open".

Change

```
<IconButton
 color="primary"
 onClick={() => {
   setIsOpenEmergencyContact(true);
 }}
>
```

To

```
<IconButton
 color="primary"
 onClick={() => {
   setActiveEmergencyContactId(customer.id);
 }}
>
```

When the user opens the popup, we now store the ID of the customer which that popup related to.

Change

```
             <PatientEmergencyPopup
                        items={
                          {
                            fullName: fullName,
                            mobileNumber: mobileNumber,
                            relation: relation
                          }
                        }
                        width={'25%'} height={'15vh'}
                        isOpenEmergencyContact={isOpenEmergencyContact}
                        setIsOpenEmergencyContact={setIsOpenEmergencyContact}/>
```

To

```
             <PatientEmergencyPopup
                        items={
                          {
                            fullName: fullName,
                            mobileNumber: mobileNumber,
                            relation: relation
                          }
                        }
                        width={'25%'} height={'15vh'}
                        isOpenEmergencyContact={activeEmergencyContactId === customer.id}
                        onClose={() => setActiveEmergencyContactId(null)}/>
```

This part is the crucial bit. Notice the prop that controls if it's open is an expression that only evaluates to true for the one which has a matching customer id we stored earlier when they clicked the icon button. When the popup closes, it sets the ID of the active popup back to null.

**PatientPopup**

In order to support the change of the prop above on `PatientPopup` (`setIsOpenEmergencyContact` to `onClose`).

Change

```
export const PatientPopup = (props) => {
  const {
    width = '25%',
    height = '15vh',
    items = {},
    isOpenEmergencyContact = false, // Set a default value here
    setIsOpenEmergencyContact
  } = props;
  return (
    <Popup
      open={isOpenEmergencyContact}
      closeOnDocumentClick
      onClose={() => setIsOpenEmergencyContact(false)}
    >
```

To

```
export const PatientPopup = (props) => {
  const {
    width = '25%',
    height = '15vh',
    items = {},
    isOpenEmergencyContact = false, // Set a default value here
    onClose
  } = props;
  return (
    <Popup
      open={isOpenEmergencyContact}
      closeOnDocumentClick
      onClose={onClose}
    >
```

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: It is pretty much almost definitely the problem. Can you post your entire newly edited `PatientTable` file as an addition edit to your original question so I can check it?

Comment: Also note I only dealt with emergency contact popup, not the other ones (though same strategy can be applied there)

Comment: Ah actually, im also wondering if the customer does have unique ID fields for each one with no conflicts? I.e. no two items in `customers` share the same ID? And the ID field is always set for each customer and not null or undefined?

Comment: Problem solved, Customer.id was undefined changed the parameter to rely on customer.username ( in my implementation username is unique so I can use that )

Comment: Yep that works!